Cavity shading in different model sizes problem
I have a trouble with cavity shading in viewport. I really like using it, but I notice it doesn't work as I would expect with bigger objects.
Is there a way to make it more visible keeping the desired objects size too?
Here is an example of object with length of 26mm, the valleys inside the windows are properly visible. You can clearly see where the edges ends and valleys starts.


Here is the same house but 10x bigger, notice that the edges next to windows are not visible at all.


How can I set it to display it better without changing the size of actual model?
Best,
Piotrek

Those are as far as I dependent on the distance you view the edges at, rather than the size of the model itself. Obviously larger models have to be viewed from further apart, hence why they seem to be less visible. Maybe play with the Distance setting inside the Gear button next to the Cavity settings, but those are prone to produce banding artifacts
